# How can I troubleshoot a router.js:958 error while processing route: item in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-1

Any thoughts as to how this can be fixed -- I have not a clue!
It works fine until an upgrade is done.  I have tried multiple times with various versions but no go.

post-upgrade:
router.js:958 Error while processing route: item You must provide a param `idPath`.
and
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: You must provide a param `idPath`.

bower.json
original
{
"name": "shepherd",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"bootstrap": "~3.3.2",
"ember": "~1.10.0",
"handlebars": "~3.0.0",
"jquery": "~1.11.3"
} }
# updated(attempt)
{
"name": "shepherd",
"private": true,
"ignore": [
"**/.*",
"node_modules",
"bower_components",
"test",
"tests"
],
"dependencies": {
"jquery": "^3.7.0",
"bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
"handlebars": "^4.7.7",
"ember": "^2.0"
} }

```
# tab config  index.html: <script src="config.js"></script>
# consumed by app.js
<script src="app.js"></script>
var config = {}
config.title = 'TABS Title'
config.items = [
  {name: 'T1', items: [
    {name: "NDC-A", items: [
      {name: "T1-NDCA:Z1 Stats", url: "<LINK>"},
      {name: "T1-NDCA:Z1 Graphs", url: "<LINK>"},
      {name: "T1-NDCA:Z2 Stats", url: "<LINK>"},
      {name: "T1-NDCA:Z2 Graphs", url: "<LINK>"},
    ]},
    {name: "NDC-B", items: [
      {name: "T1-NDCB:Z1 Stats", url: "<LINK>"},
      {name: "T1-NDCB:Z1 Graphs", url: "<LINK>"},
      {name: "T1-NDCB:Z2 Stats", url: "<LINK>"},
      {name: "T1-NDCB:Z2 Graphs", url: "<LINK>"},
    ]},
   ]},
]
```

[FYI: tabs sample as generated via above config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCZBF.png)
# app.js index.html:

```
    var App = Ember.Application.create({
    })
    
    App.initializer({
        name: 'config',
        initialize: function(container, app) {
            app.config = Ember.copy(config)
        },
    })
    
    App.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource('item', {path: '/*idPath'})
    })
    
   // fails here
    
    App.ItemRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.TitleHandler, App.ItemFactory, {
        model: function(params) {
            var items = this.getItems(App.config.items)
            var item = this.getItem(items, params.idPath)
            **// 'item' and 'items' are both populated as expected**
            if (!item) {
                return this.transitionTo('item', '')
            }
            this.setTitle(item.title)
            return item
            **// FAILS HERE 'port return'**
        },
    })
```